# Using Struct in OpenCL

Tags: opencl

I want to initialize a data structure in OpenCL. In C++, the initialization of the structure is like:

```
typedef struct mystruct{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    mystruct(){
        x = 0.0;
        y = 0.0;
        z = 0.0;
    }
}mystruct;
```

How to do this in OpenCL ?

Comment: Just a suggestion, if you just want to define a simple struct (as your example), use the build-in type, i.e. float4, as much as possible.

Comment: Does it because it is more efficiency?

Comment: Yes. It won't make much difference if you only have 3 variables to initialize though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You typedef the struct the same way as in C and then initialize it with

```
mystruct foo = {1.0, 2.1, 3.2};
```

If you want the default constructor like behaviour of C++ you could just write a function that looks like

```
mystruct
initMystruct ()
{
    mystruct foo = {0., 0., 0.};
    return foo;
}
```

Comment: You can also do it one line: `mystruct initMyStruct() {return (mystruct) {0., 0., 0.};}`.